# How should I handle storage in a WinUI 3 App that is both packaged and unpackaged?

Tags: c#, file, uwp, storage, winui

so I have a WinUi 3 app that is right now developed in a packaged format (MSIX).
However, shipping the app outside of the MS Store in that format is quite annoying (specifically the signing and sideloading.)
Every user has to first trust my self-signed certificate and then install the app.

I would like to publish the app as an unpackaged version as well, but the Windows.Storage API is not supported in unpackaged apps due to package identity missing.

See:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-supported-api
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/modernize-packaged-apps

I also tried this, but it doesn't seem to work:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/tutorial-unpackaged-deployment?tabs=csharp

Any suggestions on how to handle this, or what API to use?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you checked my reply about how to handle storage in a WinUI3 packaged and unpackaged App?

Comment: @JunjieZhu-MSFT Hi, sorry, completely forgot about your reply... Thanks for bringing it up again.
Issue is: I'm shipping both Packaged and Unpackaged at the same time... How would I go about doing that? (Ideally I just switch the config in VS, and it just works both ways...)

Comment: You could try using `System.IO.File` to handle storage, instead of `Windows.Storage API`, it works both in packaged and unpacked project.

Comment: @JunjieZhu-MSFT Hi, thanks, I just got around to trying it, and it seems to work! I would have to detect whether the App is running as packed vs unpackaged though, since the unpackaged app doesn't have a LocalState folder, right? How would I go about that if you don't mind me asking? Also, do I need to specify any permissions etc. for the packaged app (Storage Access or something)?

Comment: Why not use `System.IO.File` in both packed and unpackaged app? WinUI3 app is packaged with `capability runFullTrust`, there is no need to declare other permissions here.

Comment: OK, so I just use plain System.IO in both, and just write to %appdata%? Will this cause any issues should I decide to publish to the ms store?

Comment: As far as I know, packaged and unpackaged programs will get different results when accessing %appdata%.

Comment: Hi, sorry I never got back to you (Rewriting my appdata logic was kind of a pain, and then I just kind of forgot...). Actually this worked just fine. However, there is one thing to note: When you access the appdata folder from a packaged application, it will go to a virtual file system rather than to default %appdata%, and therefore not show up there. This is completely transparent to the code though, so watch out if you intend for other applications to access the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is recommended that you use [System.IO.File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file?view=net-6.0) to handle storage in unpackaged WinUi3 app. It is supported in WinUI3 unpackaged project.